# Analog low pass filter noise versus anti-aliasing effect

Tags: low-pass, aliasing

I am designing a nano-volt-sensitive, 32-bit ADC system for research.

The signal of interest is 10~100 uV and DC to 100Hz the goal is 10nV sensitive system.

The signal will be amplified by a pre-amplifier with a gain of 2000 and will pass through an analog filter for anti-aliasing purposes.

Since the 32-bit ADC (LTC2508-32) will operating at 4k SPS, I would like to add a low pass filter to attenuate the signal over Nyquist frequency, 2kHz.

Here are my questions:

1. How should I balance the noise added by the multi-stage analog filter and distortion from aliasing? How can I evaluate the effect of aliasing after ADC as an equivalent input-referred noise or any other method so that I can fix the specification of the analog filter?
2. For the specified analog filter, what methods can I apply to suppress noise as much as possible? (ex. noise from resister.) Would the *LTC2057 be a suitable opamp for the job? Any keywords for further research would be appreciated.

*add Jan 27: ltc2057 datasheet https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2057f.pdf

Comment: What is the noise figure of your pre-amp from DC to 2kHz, and what is the nature of the signal?

Comment: Take a look at page 22 in the [datasheet.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/250832fc.pdf)  You might not need a steep cutoff on the low pass filter.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Spectral noise of pre-amp at 1kHz would be 1.3nV, and voltage noise at 0 - 10Hz would be 40 nV peak-to-peak. You can consider it as and EEG. It is a kind of neural electric signal.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for your time. I did read that part but I am not quite sure that is the best option for accuracy. Would you recommend using that digital filter instead of a steep analog filter? If so, could you recommend any figure that I can start from? Maybe 100hz -3dB, 2k -40dB?

Comment: _"Spectral noise of pre-amp at 1kHz would be 1.3nV"_ - do you mean 1.3nV/√Hz?

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes :)

Comment: ayiee 32bit? how many meaningful bits do you actually want out of this? (i.e. what is full scale?)

Comment: _"Would the ADS2507 be a suitable opamp for the job?"_ - Google doesn't believe such a thing exists. Can you supply a link to the datasheet?

Comment: @BruceAbbott My apologies. It was typo. It is LTC2057. I made correction to the question and append data sheet :)